# receive data from emscripten fetch

Tags: c++, emscripten

I'm using Emscripten to read a csv file, I set the attributes and call the fetch like this in main:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::cout << "Start main" << std::endl;
  emscripten_fetch_attr_t attr;
  emscripten_fetch_attr_init(&attr);
  strcpy(attr.requestMethod, "GET");
  attr.attributes = EMSCRIPTEN_FETCH_LOAD_TO_MEMORY;
  attr.onsuccess = downloadSucceeded;
  attr.onerror = downloadFailed;
  emscripten_fetch(&attr, "data/alpha.csv");
```

the downloadSucceeded function is like this:

```
void downloadSucceeded(emscripten_fetch_t *fetch) {
  printf("Finished downloading %llu bytes from URL %s.\n", fetch->numBytes, fetch->url);
  // The data is now available at fetch->data[0] through fetch->data[fetch->numBytes-1];
  //printf("%s\n", fetch->data[0]);
  //std::cout << fetch->data[0] << std::endl;
  
  std::string s( reinterpret_cast< char const* >(fetch->data) ) ;
  std::cout << s << std::endl;

  emscripten_fetch_close(fetch); // Free data associated with the fetch.
}
```

How can I get back the value of s in the main?
I'm new to Emscripten so if you also tell me of a suitable resource to fill my knowledge gap I would appreciate it.

Comment: Seems you are really looking for a synchronous fetch, see [here](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/fetch.html#synchronous-fetches) in particular the comment in the code starting `// The data is now available ...`

Comment: Thank you so much, I copied the code and put in main, yet it returns : "Downloading (null) failed, HTTP failure status code: 0."
Where do you think would be the problem?

Comment: The error message suggests that the URL to download from is missing (it would be where '(null)' is in the message). But I'm no expert on emscripten.